# Any online tool to apply escape characters to a given string for ant script

Tags: ant, escaping, stringescapeutils

Hi i want to replace a token value in ant script with following string

```
<TagType Name="some name" param1="prefix=%s" param2="_default" />
```

since we cannot give directly `'<','"','%'` into an ant script, we need to use escape sequences like `'&lt;','&quot;'..`

Is there any online tool which can apply escape characters for a given string?
I hope already there are tools for this :)

---

For a given string like this

```
<TagType Name="some name" param1="prefix=%s" param2="_default" />
```

I need escaped string like this

```
&lt;TagType Name=&quot;some name&quot; param1=&quot;prefix=%s&quot; param2=&quot;_default&quot; /&gt;
```

Comment: Can you update your question to give a bit more detail? Are you replacing the entire line, or you need to replace the values contained in that line?

Comment: need to replace value with given line

Comment: What value with the given line? You have an Ant script with a parameter for this particular task line? Or, do you need to replace _some name_? Can you show a bit of your Ant script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last i found this online tool which does the job of xml escaping.
http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-escape.html